# Catching Exceptions on initialisation of DbContext

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, exception, entity-framework-core

I've been attempting to catch exceptions being generated when a table is doesn't match its' counterpart entity but can't for the life of me work out where I need to be doing the exception handling.

The database contexts are being added in the `ConfigureServices` method on Startup (trimmed for readability)

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection Services)
{
    ...

    Services.AddDbContext<AccountsContext>(Options =>
        Options.UseSqlServer(
            ApplicationConfig.GetConnectionString("Accounts")
        )
    );
    Services.AddDbContext<SupportContext>(Options =>
        Options.UseSqlServer(
            ApplicationConfig.GetConnectionString("Support")
        )
    );

    ...

    Services.AddMvc(Options =>
    {
        Options.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter());
    });
}
```

These contexts are being generated using the `Scaffold-DbContext` command packaged with "Entity Framework Core .NET Command Line Tools" NuGet.

Tracing the execution flow through, I can see it's unlikely I'll be able to (or would want to) handle catching of exceptions in the `ConfigureServices` method, as although they're defined there, they're not actually initialised until the dependency is called. I've also scrounged through the `DbContext` and `ModelBuilder` objects looking for a way to hook out a raised exception but haven't had any luck in that respect.

I'm currently considering making a custom DbContext class that inherits the original, purely to add exception handling in at this level; would this be a viable course?

I'm unable to wrap the overridden `DbContext.OnModelCreating` method in a try-catch as this code is largely fluid and any edits will be wiped with the next regeneration run that happens.

As an aside; and I don't know if it'll be useful, but, I have separated out the constructors into a separate partial, as these aren't generated with the rest of the code they need to be saved from being overwritten, an example of one is below.

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace InterfaceLayer.Entities
{
    public partial class AccountsContext
    {
        public AccountsContext(
            DbContextOptions<AccountsContext> ContextOptions
        ) : base(ContextOptions) { }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I should aim to catch these exceptions?

Comment: Something like you're describing is a critical error. There's no way to recover from it. As such, it makes very little sense to attempt to catch it. There's far better ways to handle this type of situation, such as integration testing combined with automated builds/testing in a release pipeline. In other words, find out if there's an issue with the database schema *before* you release, and fail fast.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree, luckily we have a slow pipeline & this will only ever effect the dev branch; the main goal is to provide meaningful output to devs (basically a gentle reminder to run the update scripts) when they crash headlong into this issue

Comment: Even in Dev, you can make your builds fail when tests fail. That should be all the reminder they need.

Comment: Oh I'm with you there, unfortunately the company isn't willing to "waste development time" writing tests ("we'll allocate time for that when we've released the product"), otherwise that would be my immediate reaction. I'm sneaking them in where I can but I'm the only one in the company running unit tests currently.

Comment: Eek. I suppose you've already explained to them the "development time" involved in rolling back releases because something broke, fixing unforeseen bugs and regressions, etc. Having an automated integration, build and release pipeline with testing is an investment that pays for itself many times over.

Comment: Yuuup, but it's easier to see n hours written off before a deadline for purpose X versus time absorbed into development tasks that doesn't get reported as time wasted due to guessing instead of testing

Comment: It's stupid that you have to, but if I were you, I'd start keeping a log. Anytime you have to work on a bug or something that following best practices could have avoided, log the issue, how much time it took, and how it could have been prevented. When you've got some significant data, take it to management again.